# Cannot set cookie, but only in browsers where the cookie was not set before

Tags: php, cookies

I have a cookie that I set with the PHP code:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

On my localhost it sets and works. On a browser (Chrome in this instance) the cookie sets if it was set successfully before (Upgrading to PHP 8+ started this issue). But if it is trying to set in a browser where the cookie has never been set before, it will not set (still Chrome, just a different profile).

I have confirmed that the code is being executed due to parallel commands, so I am at a loss as to what is happening. And I have deleted the cookie on the profiles where it works, and it is able to be set again. And to delete the cookie I am using the code:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, "", time() - (86400 * 30), "/");
```

If I revert back to PHP 7.4, the issue persists.

Comment: I'll take any guesses you have too. In the browsers with no history of the cookie, it does work on my localhost. On the live server I have tested with no caching, no firewalls, nothing that should be blocking anything.

Comment: When you use your browser's inspection tools, can you set the cookie being supplied from the server to the client?

Comment: Things that cookies depend upon are the clock and the domain. So, do the clocks on both the server and client have the correct time? Are you using a domain, or just an IP address? Next, `setcookie()` returns a boolean, is it `true` or `false`? You also do not describe how test whether a cookie was successfully set.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I can see that the cookie hasn't been set in developer tools. Plus the cookie triggers and UI change that isn't happening of course. The server time is correct as is the client.

Comment: I'd next turn on full error reporting, specifically to see if a "headers were already sent" message

Comment: I am in WordPress and have DEBUG enabled and there are no errors being reported through any of this. It is currently on PHP v8.0 on GoDaddy servers.

Comment: This needs more context then, than just "I am in WordPress", and a single line of code.